# Rightarrow at 45 degrees in equation

Tags: equations, arrows

I have attempted to get this output:

[image]

Instead I got this:

[image]

Can you help me get the correct output?  Thanks!

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\begin{document}

$\zeta\underset{overshoot\searrow}{\nearrow}\Rightarrow$P.M$\nearrow$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `array`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITSMath}
\begin{document}

\[
  \zeta\nearrow\underset
   {\mathclap{\displaystyle\Searrow \text{overshoot}\searrow}}
   {\Rightarrow \text{P.M.} \nearrow}
\]  

\[
\zeta\nearrow\underset
   {\mathclap{\Searrow \text{ overshoot }\searrow}}
   {\Rightarrow \text{ P.M. } \nearrow}
\]  

\[
  \zeta\nearrow
  \underset
     {\mathrlap{\displaystyle\Searrow\text{ overshoot}\searrow}}
     {\mathrlap{\Rightarrow\text{P.M.} \nearrow}} 
\]  
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

or with an `array`

```
\[
  \zeta\nearrow
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}ll}
     \Rightarrow\text{P.M.} \nearrow \\
     \Searrow\text{ overshoot}\searrow
  \end {array}
\]
```

Comment: thanks for your solution.  In your first solution, how to get the double arrows to be aligned?  Thanks!

Comment: see edited answer